# Crystal subreport in page footer won't print

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I'm attempting to modify a Crystal Report that prints our invoices.  The original request was to allow the report to print the T&C (Terms & Conditions) Page at the end of each invoice.  I was able to do this successfully.  However, when I presented it to the end-user they explained that they don't want to have to print each invoice individually.  (Makes sense...)  However, I have not been able to successfully provide results as of yet.  Below are my challenges/questions:

I obviously can't expect the Report Footer to print multiple times within the report so I inserted a section below my current page footer for the T&C.  I wanted to add a 'New Page Before' but that option is grayed out.  After attempting to identify what was causing this to gray out without success (content that was marked 'can grow' or that was too large for a section is my understanding) I decided to attempt creating a subreport in the new page footer & I marked that section of the report as 'New Page Before' so that the T&C would be placed on a new page between each invoice.  I finally got the first line of the T&C to show up but the rest was cut off and the next page started the next invoice.

Does anyone know why my subreport in the page footer - to display a single page print of our company's T&C - isn't working as intended?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Renee'

Comment: Maybe you could group by invoice ID and print TOC at group footer? Page footer is not clearly related to records-groups anyway.

Comment: in sub report where did you place the T&C? I mean  in which section?

Answer (score 0):

Open the SubReport by right clicking and going to Edit from the main report.
Resize the Detail section of the Subreport. This should help displaying all of the T&C